# FileDialog generating GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged

Tags: java, gtkdialog

My java code is generating the following message when I create a open FileDialog and make it visible.  I have checked the code against code examples and I can't find anything wrong.  And I am passing in the parent frame reference into the constructor.  This is the code example:

```
public void open() {
    if (openAreYouSure()) {
    MyFilenameFilter filter = new MyFilenameFilter(Editor.JAWS_FILE_TYPE);

    FileDialog d = new FileDialog(frame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    d.setFilenameFilter(filter);
    d.setBackground(lightSteelBlue3);

    if (!mostRecentDir.equals(""))
        d.setDirectory(mostRecentDir);

    d.setVisible(true);

    String path = d.getDirectory();
    String file = d.getFile();

    if (path != null && file != null) {
        Editor.logger.info("opened file: " + path + file);
        newSession();

        mostRecentDir = path;
        openFile(path + file);
    }
    }
}
```

This comes out when the d.setVisible(true); is called.

```
Gtk-Message: 12:10:44.979: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

This is the version of java I am using on centos 7.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

All the write ups on this type of messages say its caused because you didn't pass in the parent into the dialog you are created, but I am in the constructor.  This is happening for all pop dialog my application is creating.

Does anyone have any idea how to suppress or fix this problem?  I am not seeing any java bug report on this, but I assume there is somewhere.

Comment: If you are calling this method within the application's main class Constructor then most likely the `frame` hasn't finished initializing yet. Make the call after everything is initialized: `public MyClassConstructor () { initializeComponents(); open(); }`. If the first thing to be seen is the file dialog then set the frame's setVisible property to false until a valid file selection is made then set it to true.

Comment: The main function is calling the editor class which creates the main frame, adds the listeners, drop down menus, etc. to the frame.  For the menus that will need to know the main frame, the frame variable is passed into them via the class constructor.  The editor constructor function then returns and the main calls editor.start().  The first thing start does is make the main frame visible.  So initialization should be completed by the time someone selects the File->Open callback.  Making main frame visible before I setup the file menu options doesn't stop the message coming out.